# mplayer doesn't like popen suddenly?

Tags: c++, linux, popen, mplayer

Been stumped over a problem with popen for a few days.

The code:

```
int main(){
 FILE *fp = popen("mplayer /home/linaro/Music/cp.mp3", "r");
char buffer[1028]; 
while (fgets(buffer, 1028, fp) != NULL) 
{ 
  std::cerr<<buffer; 
} 
pclose(fp);
fp = 0;
return 0;
```

}

was run at the shop on a linaro embedded controller. Ran fine, no errors. Even though the code is simple (Just plays a coldplay song on execution and then quits) it seems to be causing me more grief than one would think.

If I copy and paste the command itself into a normal bash shell, it runs fine. And what's worse, is it ran fine up until it got plugged in somewhere else. I'm not sure if it is now being connected to via a headphone jack versus before it was in a line out jack.

Regardless, the error I get when I run it is (summarized down to the relevant part)

> MPlayer svn r34540 (Ubuntu), built with gcc-4.6 (C) 2000-2012 MPlaye4
>
> Team mplayer: could not connect to socket mplayer: No such file or
>
> directory Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use
>
> your remote control.
>
> Playing /home/linaro/Music/cp.mp3 libavformat version 53.21.1
>
> (external) Mismatching header version 53.19.0 Audio only file format
>
> detected. Clip info: Title: The Scientist Artist: Coldplay Album: A
>
> Rush Of Blood To The Head Year: 2002 Comment:  Genre: Unknown Load
>
> subtitles in /home/linaro/Music/ Requested audio codec family [mpg123]
>
> (afm=mpg123) not available. Enable it at compilation. Opening audio
>
> decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders libavcodec version
>
> 53.35.0 (external) Mismatching header version 53.32.2 AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 
>   ch, floatle, 256.0 kbit/9.07% (ratio: 32002->352800) Selected audio
>
> codec: [ffmp3float] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG layer-3 audio) Home
>
> directory not accessible: Permission denied AO: [pulse] Init failed:
>
> Connection refused Failed to initialize audio driver 'pulse' Home
>
> directory not accessible: Permission denied [AO_ALSA] alsa-lib:
>
> pcm_hw.c:1293:(snd_pcm_hw_open) open '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0p' failed (-22):
>
> Invalid argument [AO_ALSA] Playback open error: Invalid argument
>
> Failed to initialize audio driver 'alsa' [AO SDL] Samplerate: 44100Hz
>
> Channels: Stereo Format floatle [AO SDL] using aalib audio driver. [AO
>
> SDL] Unsupported audio format: 0x1d. [AO SDL] Unable to open audio: No
>
> available audio device Failed to initialize audio driver 'sdl:aalib'
>
> Could not open/initialize audio device -> no sound. Audio: no sound
>
> Video: no video

Again, if I copy and paste the exact command it executes via popen into the console, it begins playing. It fails if pass -ao alsa, -ao pulse, -ao oss as well, which has me completely stumped. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
Linux is linaro, based on Ubuntu 12.04  using arm CPU

Comment: I see a lot of permission denied errors. How do you start your C program? What does happen if you replcae your C program with a bash script doing the same? Also, please add which exact linux distribution version you are using, and if SELinux or AppArmor are in the play.

Comment: From `man popen()`: "*This command is passed to /bin/sh*" So what does `/bin/sh` start in your test environmnet?

Comment: Jonas : I am executing it with sudo, however the mplayer on its own from terminal is running both with and without sudo.

Comment: @alk not sure how to answer that. I can do a printennv if you think that'll help. Again the most odd part is that it worked initially and then stopped.

Comment: Updated question to include Linux version

Comment: You might like to check were `/bin/sh` most likely links to.

Comment: @alk - printenv links it to /bin/bash, which hasn't changed since it was working initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue wound up being as Jonas and alk suggested -- permissions. Something along the way changed how it ran, but at the end of the day the dirty fix was to just include

```
su - user -c ' mplayer ... '
```

To the line being called.